# sybase ASE connect to python - ct_connect(): Protocol driver call to parse connection information failed

Tags: sybase

i am trying to extract data periodically from a sybase ASE 15.5 db using python.
The sybpydb module has been installed through sybase 15.7 SDK and i am getting this error with the basic test script:

```
import sybpydb
conn = sybpydb.connect(user = 'user' , password = 'mypw' , servername = 'theserver')****
```

the error which i am getting is

> sybpydb.OperationalError: ct_connect(): network packet layer: internal net library error: Protocol driver call to parse connection information failed

i have verified that the db can be reached via the `dsedit` program and ping was successful. Any suggestion guys?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your sql.ini file in

```
c:\sysbase\ini
```

folder and check your hostname or IP address for your DSN.